# How to set PHP Max_Input_vars?

Tags: php, ini

I am using PHP version 5.6.12 on an Apache server and I am having a hard time setting Max_Input_Vars. I have looked online and I have inserted the following into my php.ini file.

```
php_value max_input_vars 5000
php_value suhosin.get.max_vars 5000
php_value suhosin.post.max_vars 5000
php_value suhosin.request.max_vars 5000
```

However, when I look at my phpinfo this variable is still set to the default 1000.How can I set this to 5000?